# convert first two columns and Headders into charater

Tags: r

.I read one file as like this

```
data<-read.delim('ty.txt',sep = "\t",header = T,check.names = FALSE
```

and it is in list format as like this

```
Name  Id     xxx    dddd  vvvv   vvsa
aws  12.1  2.300   5.320 6.3254 21.365
```

I need to round this list (Except first two columns and Headers) and I did as like this

```
myData[] <- lapply(data,round,2)
```

But I got error as like this "Error in Math.factor(c(566L, 401L, 749L, 106L, 805L, 574L, 295L, 593L,  :
‘round’ not meaningful for factors".

Is there any way to convert fist two columns and all the headers into character , because I need to do it for multiple files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simpler answer would be just trying:

`myData[, 2:ncol(myData)] <- round(myData[, 2:ncol(myData)], 2)`